# Is there any way to link normal website login page to wordpress website login page

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

i have a website in wordpress, now i have created 1 more website in core php which is similar to wordpress website. I have linked wordpress database to normal website.
Now what i want is i want to login in my 2nd website with the help of wordpress user table.
i don;t know what kind of encryption method they have use. that's why i'm not able to login from my 2nd website.
i saw some article which tell that wordpress use md5 in older version, now they use password_hash
i tried both method
but unable to get result.
Can anyone tell me what kind of encryption method they use in latest version.
or how can i make that method in php

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by loading the wp-load.php file into your custom application and using the Wordpress build-in function

```
wp_authenticate( $username, $password );
```

You can find further documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/

Update 23-03-2022
In my testing lab I created a file called alt-login.php in de document root that also contains the wp-config.php. In the file I put the following code

```
<?php
include("wp-load.php");

wp_authenticate("user","password");
```

To test just load the file and enter a valid set of credentials. You can var_dump the return value of wp_authenticate to verify if the authentication was succesful, if not you will get an error message. There are no other dependencies to load other than wp-load.php, unlike mentioned in comments.

Comment: I tried above method, but its not working

Comment: wp-load file is dependent on other file. if i only use this file then i have to use all dependent file

Comment: I have updated my answer, I have tested it and it fully works. with latest version of wordpress.